# Download nuget.exe using Powershell

Tags: powershell, nuget, psake

Can someone provide an example powershell script to bootstrap (aka download) NuGet.exe for a fresh system that only has the .NET 4.5 SDK installed?

I would like to use psake to automate my entire build process and would prefer to not upload NuGet.exe into my VCS repository.

Comment: I have updated my .NET projects to no longer use the pre-NuGet-v2.7 package restore method with a NuGet.target file and would like my CI server and local builds to be able to build assuming that no system dependencies are installed such as NuGet.exe via chocolatey or similar. I would like my psake script to download NuGet.exe, invoke NuGet restore, and then build, test, package etc my project.

Comment: Hi Johnny, what I mean is, can you provide your example of an attempt to write a powershell script that downloads NuGet.exe on fresh system that only has the .NET 4.5 SDK installed, along with details of what errors were encountered by this example. That's the sort of due diligence we're looking for. Hope that helps.